# Why does the cli command for generating a resolver throw exception?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

As you can see in the [cli documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate#resolver), there is a command for generating a resolver. However when I try to use it from my VS Code terminal, it throws an exception -

> An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "resolver" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".

Am I doing something wrong? Anyone used it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are not using the most recent version of the angular cli.
The resolver schematic was only added recently (this year's October), see this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/45c0b50998f6f109f4f20e496b74db82b07d1ac0#diff-238d004212562ee45537561d263cd963ca8173523d39a920900d18d89b10b32f).

It should work fine with the current version `11.0.1`.
You can verify the available schematic commands when you run `ng generate --help`.

Comment: Yes I was using version `10.2.0`. Just updated and the command is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Still not working for me on both `11.0.1` and `11.0.4`.  `ng generate --help` produced every schematic listed here: https://angular.io/cli/generate, except "resolver".

Comment: Strange. You could check in your node_modules if for some reason `@angular/schematics` has the wrong version and if so update it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command `ng generate r [name]`